# Handle KeyDown event of a ComboBox column inside a C1FlexGrid

Tags: vb.net, combobox, keydown, key-events, c1flexgrid

I have a ComboBox "I named it Combo" that is loaded inside a C1FlexGrid "I named it fgMain" in the second column and I want to handle keyboard to make pressing enter on this combobox available for users.

I Use this code to create the combobox and to populate it with data :

```
fgMain.Cols(2).Editor = Combo    
Combo.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal    
Dim dap As New OleDbDataAdapter()    
        Dim dat As New DataTable()
        dap.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT EmpInfo.ManualId, EmpInfo.Name FROM EmpInfo;", conn)
        dap.Fill(dat)
        Combo.DataSource = dat
        Combo.DisplayMember = "Name"
        Combo.ValueMember = "ManualId"
```

I use this code to handle pressing enter on any cell in column 2 in c1flexgrid it only handle 1st enter pressed on any cell in column 2 and make the drop down list of combobox appears :

```
Private Sub fgMain_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles fgMain.KeyDown    
    Select Case e.KeyCode    
        Case Keys.Enter    
            Select Case fgMain.Selection.c1    
                Case 2    
                    fgMain.StartEditing(fgMain.Selection.BottomRow, 2)    
                    e.SuppressKeyPress = True    
                    e.Handled = True    
            End Select
     End Select
```

now I need to handle if user selected his desired item then he will press enter for the second time...my problem is when i press second enter to choose a choice the selected item, it appears in "  fgMain(e.row, 2) " only for less than one second then the whole row disappears and fgMain(e.row,2) became empty

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem is occurring because you are using [KeyPress](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/#C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGridBase~KeyPress_EV.html) event of the FlexGrid, whereas you want the ComboBox to handle the KeyPress event. You can either use the ComboBox's event or, if you need some reference of grid use the [KeyPressEdit](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/#C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGridBase~KeyPressEdit_EV.html) event. The KeyPressEdit event corresponds to the System.Windows.Forms.Control.KeyPress event, except it fires when the grid is in edit mode (in this case, the control that receives the key is the editor, not the grid itself).

Refer the following snippet:

```
Private Sub fgM_KyDwnEdt(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEditEventArgs) Handles fgMain.KeyDownEdit
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Enter
            Select Case fgMain.Selection.c1
                Case 2
                    fgMain.StartEditing(fgMain.Selection.BottomRow, 2)
                    e.Handled = True
            End Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Vishwakarma for your help. But my problem isn't to start editing of `fgMain.StartEditing(fgMain.Selection.BottomRow, 2)` . my problem is to make selected item stay in `fgMain(fgMain.Selection.BottomRow, 2)` after second enter pressed to confirm selecting this item .I want to handle  pressing enter in `fgMain_KeyDownEdit` to receive data not to enter edit mode cause KeyDownEdit event fires when cell already in edit mode "Far as I know"

Comment: I'm using [KeyDown](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/#C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid~KeyDown_EV.html) Event not [KeyPress](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/#C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGridBase~KeyPress_EV.html) Event

Comment: If you could use keypressedit instead of keypress, or keydownedit instead of keydown, you would see the difference I was trying to explain

Comment: Mr. Vishwakarma
First let me thank u for ur help. I tried ur code and it didn't work. my C1FlexGrid "fgMain" still suffer from the same thing that when i press second enter to confirm my choice from combo the selected item appears in fg(e.row, 2) "cell which contain combo" for less than 1 second and disappears . I really need event responsible for Ending Editing inside cell to handle it to end when user click enter "the second enter"

Answer (score 0):

my team leader told me this isn't good way to but a combobox into a C1FlexGrid. u can just use this way

```
Dim tmpStyle As CellStyle
Dim MyCmd As New OleDbCommand
Dim DbReader As OleDbDataReader
MyCmd.Connection = conn
MyCmd.CommandText = "SELECT EmpInfo.ManualId, EmpInfo.Name FROM EmpInfo;"
DbReader = MyCmd.ExecuteReader
dtMap.Clear()
Do While DbReader.Read
    dtMap.Add(DbReader("ManualId"), DbReader("Name"))
Loop
tmpStyle = fgMain.Styles.Add("Name")
tmpStyle.DataType = GetType(Integer)
tmpStyle.DataMap = dtMap
fgMain.Cols(2).Style = tmpStyle
DbReader.Close()
MyCmd.Dispose()
```

u also don't need KeyPress event or KeyPressEdit event to handle enter pressing. u just need to handle AfterEdit event to handle what happen after editing any cell in ur combobox column. hope this was enough to help anyone will ever need to put a combobox into a C1FlexGrid